# Why are the types of the destructured array values inferred from the type of the original array?

Tags: typescript

```
let arr = [7, "hello", true];
let [a, ...bc] = arr;

typeof bc :  (string | number | boolean)[]
```

why `bc`type is `(string | number | boolean)`

expect:

because `bc = ["hello", true]`, so `bc` type should be `(string | boolean)[]`

Answer (score 2):

Per default `arr` is inferred as `(string | number | boolean)[]` because TypeScript tries to infer the [*"best common type"*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type).

> When a type inference is made from several expressions, the types of those expressions are used to calculate a “best common type”. [...]
> The best common type algorithm considers each candidate type, and picks the type that is compatible with all the other candidates. [...] To correct this, explicitly provide the type when no one type is a super type of all other candidates.

That means every single item in the array is of the [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | number | boolean`. TypeScript does not know the first item you [destructure](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring) is of type `number`. Instead its type is `string | number | boolean` like all other items. Thus, the type of your destrucured item stays the same.

If you declared `arr` `as const` TypeScript can extract the type information:

```
let arr = [7, "hello", true] as const;
let [a, ...bc] = arr;
//         ^? let bc: ["hello", true]
```

As the documentation states "best common type" corrections can be made with an explicit type annotation:

```
let arr: [number, ...(string | boolean)[]] = [7, "hello", true];
let [a, ...bc] = arr;
//         ^? let bc: (string | boolean)[]
```